# Запрос на вывод данных из двух таблиц в одну

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Имеются 2 таблицы. Категории и продукты. Пытаюсь вывести, так чтобы поле parent было равно полю id из таблицы категории, а так же что бы у каждой категории были видны продукты. Пытался сделать inner join + union. Но желаемого результата не достиг. Наглядно это выглядит так: Компьютеры->(С процессором AMD->(Электроника 1, Электроника 2), С процессором Intel->(samsung nv305, asus as450)).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или же так:

```
$array = ['Компьютеры' => [
'С процессорами AMD' => [
'DNS amd', 'Citilink amd'],
'С процессорами Intel' => [
'DNS intel', 'Citilink Intel'],
],
'Ноутбуки' => [
'С процессорами AMD' => [
'samsung nb305 amd', 'samsung ni319 amd'],
'С процессорами Intel' => [
'sony sn456 intel', 'asus as450 intel'],
]
```

Написал вот что: php вывод

```
$array = [];
   foreach ($catName as $key => $value) {
       foreach ($cats as $catkey => $catvalue) {
           if((int)$key==(int)$groupvalue['id_parent'])
           {
               $array[$value]['id_cat'] = $catkey;
               $array[$value][] = $catvalue['cat_name'];
           }
           if(array_key_exists($value, $array))
           {
               //print_r($cats[])
               if($array[$value]['id_cat']==(int)$catvalue['id_parent'])
               {
                $array[$value][] = $catkey;   
               }
            }
       }
   }
```

sql:

```
SELECT categories.id AS IdCat, categories.parent AS ParentCat, categories.name AS CatName, products.name AS ProductName
        FROM categories
        INNER JOIN products
        ON categories.id = products.id_cat
        ORDER BY IdCat
```

UNION убрал. С ним просто в конец добавляется часть таблицы.

Comment: делаете 2 join: id = id_cat и id = parent

Comment: SELECT categories.id AS IdCat, 
        categories.parent AS ParentCat, 
        categories.name AS CatName, 
        products.name AS ProductName
        FROM categories
        INNER JOIN products ON categories.id = products.id_cat
        INNER JOIN categories AS t1 ON t1.id = categories.parent
        ORDER BY IdCat; Вы  что такое имеете ввиду?

Comment: Так же с таким запросом у меня не выводится категории, если парент=0. попытался исправить объединением с таким же запросом, но с условием что парент=0. Выводится не совсем то что ожидалось....

Comment: Ну во-первых, если вы выбираете продукты, то нужно и `FROM` делать из продуктов, а присоединять "побочные" таблицы. Во-вторых, кроме `INNER JOIN` есть ещё `LEFT JOIN`, который заменяет недостающие данные `null`

Comment: Хм, тогда получается так **`LEFT JOIN categories AS t1 ON t1.id = categories.parent `**, отсеит данные из левой таблицы. Но это выведет вроде как тоже самое.

Comment: Поспешил, если выводить всё, то выходит почти то что нужно. Но данные выводятся не в том порядке.

Comment: так `ORDER BY` поменяйте

Comment: У меня есть ещё t1.  Там должны хранится данные по связанным категориям. Но я так понимаю что нужно ещё выборку делать. Чтобы получилась Компьютеры->С процессором Amd-> ... **`SELECT сategories.name, t1.name, t2.name, products.name
        FROM products
        INNER JOIN сategories ON сategories.id = products.id_cat
        LEFT JOIN сategories AS t1 ON t1.id = сategories.parent
        LEFT JOIN сategories AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.parent `** Уже без какой либо сортировки. Но получаю всё равно близко , но не то. Копать в сторону того что вывожу, или всё таки выборки

Comment: Потому что вы неправильно решаете задачу. Вам нужно искать как создать иерархический справочник в mysql php